# How do I register widget assets in Yii2?

Tags: css, widget, yii2, assets

I want to create a custom widget in yii2 with its css and js files. Inside 'components' folder I've created a 'myWidget' folder and inside of it:
- myWidget.php which extends yii\base\Widget.
- myWidgetAsset.php which extends yii\web\AssetBundle.
- views folder containing index.php file.
- assets folder containing main.css and main.js files.

Here are the codes: myWidget.php

```
namespace app\components\myWidget;

use app\components\tablaFoS\tablaFoSAsset;
use app\models\DisciplinesGrandesAreas;
use yii\base\Widget;

class myWidget extends Widget {

   public function run() {
    parent::run();

    return $this->render('index');
   }
}
```

myWidgetAsset.php

```
namespace app\components\myWidget;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class myWidgetAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = ['assets/main.css'];
    public $js = ['assets/main.js'];
    public $depends = [
    ];
}
```

When I see the generated code I got:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.css"></link>
<script src="/assets/main.js"></script>
```

instead of something like e.g.bootstrap:

```
<link href="/becyt/assets/67099f30/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're not ever registering your AssetBundle. I think what you're missing, is `myWidgetAsset::register($this->view);` before you call `return $this->render('index');` However, I'm stuck on this same issue, where my js and css assets are not registering at all, so if anyone else could chime in, I'd really appreciate it too.

Answer (score 8):

You could register your AssetBundle in the widget's `init()` function like this:

```
public function init() {
    MyAssetBundle::register( $this->getView() );
    parent::init();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To publish your asset files, you should set `sourcePath` instead of `basePath` and `baseUrl`, e.g. :

```
class myWidgetAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $sourcePath = '@app/components/myWidget/assets';
    public $css = ['main.css'];
    public $js = ['main.js'];
}
```

Read more in official guide [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-locations) :

> source assets: the asset files are located together with PHP source
>   code which cannot be directly accessed via Web. In order to use source
>   assets in a page, they should be copied to a Web directory and turned
>   into the so-called published assets.

And of course don't forget to register this asset bundle in your widget `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also register a widgets assets like

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
\marqu3s\summernote\SummernoteAsset::register($this);
```